# HP dl 380 gen9 with hp p440ar smart Array card

Tags: raid

Can I use HP smart array p420 on HP dl380p gen9 server?

The problem is that for some reasons I need Rhel 5.7 on the server.

But unfortunately there NO driver for the smart Array P440ar that came with the server for Rhel 5.7. Available only drivers from Rhel6.5.

Any  help?

Answer (score 1):

No, no and no...

The DL380 Gen9 does not work with RHEL5. It was never meant to.

*HPE OS support [compatibility matrix](http://h17007.www1.hpe.com/us/en/enterprise/servers/supportmatrix/redhat_linux.aspx#.WRDHnFLMySt)*
[image]

- If you absolutely need RHEL5, you should be using the most current RHEL5 revision (5.11) - But that will not work with this server.
- You should be using compatible hardware. A Gen8 server would be a good compromise.
- You shouldn't try to downgrade the RAID controller in the Gen9 server.
- Maybe it makes sense to consider RHEL6 or RHEL7 at this point, if your application supports it.

Answer (score 1):

Install CentOs 7 on server and then CentOs 5.7 in KVM virtualized. So you don't need to take care about hardware in the future.

Comment: Really good answer!